# Issue with Bootstrap Tab and variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, variables, bootstrap-tabs

i've issue with bootstrap tabs & a variable.

See [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr2c34hc/)

On this a variable active and height that is`$page_nav["dashboard"]["active"] = true;` in menus. And it has two submenus. As above link i want

on first tab active & heighligh this submenu `$page_nav["dashboard"]["sub"]["First_submenu"]["active"] = true;`

And on second tab active & heighlight this submenu`$page_nav["dashboard"]["sub"]["Second_submenu"]["active"] = true;`

How can i do it??
please Help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question (it really doesn't make any sense), but when looking at your fiddle, I noticed your menu stops working after two clicks on links.

Comment: usieng this variable menu are heighlight. so i want when we use tab then automatic heighlight its submenu on same page. But saubmenus has diff links

Comment: Still makes no sense. Can't you ask someone with a bit better knowledge of the English language to write it down? It's not to be an ass or something, but your English is really not understandable.